# SFML Image.saveToFile access violation

Tags: c++, sfml

So I am working on a program that generates images with shapes of random selected colors. and I want to save an image of the output so I can use shaders on the image like blurring, as well as have an output file for any purpose. Here is my main loop for the window.

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
    window.clear(Color::Black);

    for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.size(); i++)
        window.draw(rectangles[i]);

    Texture outputTexture;
    outputTexture.create(width, height);
    outputTexture.update(window);

    Image output;
    output.create(width, height);
    output = outputTexture.copyToImage();
    output.saveToFile("output.png");

    Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(outputTexture);

    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();
}
```

I have tested this with the sprite and the window draws the sprite correctly. However I am getting an error here

```
output.saveToFile("output.png");
```

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8D1527190 (sfml-graphics-2.dll) in name.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I can't seem to figure out the issue, I really need to be able to save images to a file. Thanks all for help

Comment: Hmm. Everything works here. I had to add some code to generate the RectangleShapes, but output.png is saved.

Comment: There's no point in creating the image first. `copyToImage()` creates a new copy of an image.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, the solution was to change "sfml-xxx.lib" to "sfml-xxx-d.lib" in "Additional Dependencies" property in Visual Studio.